# I already installed PHP extension in my VSCode but php is still no recognized. what to

Tags: php, laravel

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SCJKn.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0OapO.png)

I already installed php but why can't I still use php? I am new and I want to start learning Laravel for a project. please can someone help me?

your answers are deeply appreciated.

Comment: Posting a fuzzy, out of focus screen shot won't help you. I've no idea what the other screen shot is for. If you want us to help you, help us to do so. Take the [tour] and see [ask]

Comment: If what you're trying to do is to run PHP scripts from command-line / PowerShell (it's a bit hard to say given your sparse explanation), then Visual Studio Code does not play any role here. You need to head to [PHP Windows downloads](https://windows.php.net/download/) and grab a copy of the PHP interpreter (or get a third-party installer, which many people prefer).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Php is an executable that needs to be executed with arguments in the command line. Therefore, if you want to access it globally you need to put it on your path variable in your environment and tell VsCode where that executable is store. That should do the trick as far as those two items go. They get a little more complicated depending on how you do the install and where the executables are referenced. I am not sure what operating system you are using but below is a guide directly from the php team's website to the installation section of the manual.

https://www.php.net/manual/en/install.php